# .current-menu-item class on custom post type children pages - again?

Tags: posts, customization

There is the situation.
I have created the custom post type - products withfuncionality like pages - I have to create hierarchy.

f.e:

1. Chairs:

   - Oak Chair
   - Nice Chair

The weird thing happens with wp_nav_menu(). When I open the first level page Chairs and display all the Chairs childrens in theme, the nav menu for the  li item Products, gets the .current-menu-item class, but when I open the child page f.e. Oak Chair, the class disapears.

Why is that and how to set .current-menu-item class also when child page is opened?

This same problem happens again :(
WP Version 3.2.1

the ancestor-class .current-products-ancestor is not setted up :(

Comment: do you mean, that there is no .current-menu-item class on the child page?

Comment: Exactly. Only on parent page.

Comment: Actully, wordpress gives tag .current-produkts-ancestor to menu element when child page is opened. This solves my problem, actually. I can then add different color to this menu item.

Comment: This trick saves the world 
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/highlighting-wp-nav-menu-ancestor-class-w-o-children-in-nav-structure/3034#3034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this selector:

```
.current-products-ancestor
```

... to change the styles on that menu.

Comment: Yes, that is what i figured out.