# Custom Post Type .current-menu-item not applying on Custom Post Type Archive Page

Tags: custom-post-types, php, menus, templates

I am working with custom post types and I had trouble with the nav menu not getting the `.current-menu-item` on my `custom post archive page` menu item. In fact, when I was on that page or any of the `custom posts`, instead of the cpt archive menu item getting the current class, the menu item pointing to the articles was getting the `.current-menu-item` (blog page in my case).

After several hours, google, tests and hacks, I found this [thread on wordpress](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/why-does-blog-become-current_page_parent-with-custom-post-type?replies=8) and here's a copy past edited version of the workaround fix:

```
// As of WP 3.1.1 addition of classes for css styling to parents of custom post types doesn't exist.
// We want the correct classes added to the correct custom post type parent in the wp-nav-menu for css styling and highlighting, so we're modifying each individually...
// The id of each link is required for each one you want to modify
// Place this in your WordPress functions.php file

function remove_parent_classes($class)
{
  // check for current page classes, return false if they exist.
    return ($class == 'current_page_item' || $class == 'current_page_parent' || $class == 'current_page_ancestor'  || $class == 'current-menu-item') ? FALSE : TRUE;
}

function add_class_to_wp_nav_menu($classes)
{
     switch (get_post_type())
     {
        case 'artist':
            // we're viewing a custom post type, so remove the 'current_page_xxx and current-menu-item' from all menu items.
            $classes = array_filter($classes, "remove_parent_classes");

            // add the current page class to a specific menu item (replace ###).
            if (in_array('menu-item-171', $classes))
            {
               $classes[] = 'current_page_parent';
         }
            break;
     }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_class_to_wp_nav_menu');
```

This solution works when we use the menu item id, but I find it very ugly and it's impossible to use this for plugin development...

Any *other idea* for selecting the menu item corresponding to the archive page of the custom posts when we are on the archive page or on one of the custom posts in a cleaner way?

*In other words, an archive template isn't supposed to select it's own menu item out of the box?*

I'd never tought that highliting an element in the wordpress nav menu could have been a problem with custom post types, I'm a bit disapointed. Anyway, here are nnippets of codes I use to manage my custom posts (artist):

**artist.php**:

```
/****************************************************************
* Custom Post Type
****************************************************************/

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_artist' );
function custom_post_artist()
{
  $labels = array(
    [...]
    );

  register_post_type( 'artist',
    array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'menu_position' => 15,
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'excerpt'),
      'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
      'show_in_menu' => true,
      'taxonomies' => array( 'artist_genre', 'artist_music_type' ),
      'has_archive' => 'artistes',
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => __('artistes', 'ppdev'), 'with_front' => False )
      )
    );
}

/****************************************************************
* Templates
****************************************************************/

add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_tpl_function', 1 );
function include_tpl_function( $template_path )
{
  if ( get_post_type() == 'artist' )
  {
    if ( is_single() )
    {
      // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
      // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
      if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array('single-artist.php') ) )
      {
        $template_path = $theme_file;
      }
      else
      {
        $template_path = ARTIST_PATH . 'templates/single-artist.php';
      }
    } 
    else if( is_archive() )
    {
      if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array('archive-artist.php') ) )
      {
        $template_path = $theme_file;
      }
      else
      {
        $template_path = ARTIST_PATH . 'templates/archive-artist.php';
      }
    }
  }
  return $template_path;
}
```

Very basic archive template page:

**archive-artist.php**:

```
<section id="primary">
  <div id="content" role="main">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <header class="page-header">
      <h1 class="page-title">Latest artists</h1>
    </header>

      <!-- Start the Loop -->         
      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

      $thumbnail_attr = array(
        'class' => "aligncenter",
        'alt' => get_the_title()
      );

      <h2>
        <a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
      </h2>

      if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
          <a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', $thumbnail_attr ); ?>
          </a>            
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>

     <!-- Display page navigation -->
   <?php global $wp_query;
   if ( isset( $wp_query->max_num_pages ) && $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) { ?>
   <nav id="<?php echo $nav_id; ?>">
     <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Previous artists' ) ); ?></div>
     <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Next artists <span class= "meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ); ?></div>
   </nav>
   <?php };
  endif; ?>
 </div>
</section>
```

*Note: Also tested with twenty twelve theme and same issue*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer by searching in similar posts and links. I added a line to fit my needs (I wanted to prevent my blog page to get highlited when on a custom post).See this line:  `unset($classes[array_search('current_page_parent',$classes)]);`

**Solution**

```
function add_parent_url_menu_class( $classes = array(), $item = false ) {
  // Get current URL
  $current_url = current_url();

  // Get homepage URL
  $homepage_url = trailingslashit( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) );

  // Exclude 404 and homepage
  if( is_404() or $item->url == $homepage_url )
    return $classes;

  if ( get_post_type() == "artist" )
  {
    unset($classes[array_search('current_page_parent',$classes)]);
    if ( isset($item->url) )
      if ( strstr( $current_url, $item->url) )
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
  }

  return $classes;
}

function current_url() {
  // Protocol
  $url = ( 'on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
  $url .= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

  // Port
  $url .= ( '80' == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ? '' : ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
  $url .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

  return trailingslashit( $url );
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'add_parent_url_menu_class', 10, 3 );
```

[Source](http://www.rarescosma.com/2010/11/add-a-class-to-wp_nav_menu-items-with-urls-included-in-the-current-url/)

I am not a fan of this answer because it's using the url to compare the element in the menu item, but this one will work fine for different menu IDs and is ok to use in a plugin. Hope it helps someone, lost a couple hours for something I consider a wordpress bug.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this problem when extending the [Walker_Nav_Menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) was to skip check if `current_page_parent` when C.P.T. I identified C.P.Ts following this [stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/highlighting-wp-nav-menu-ancestor-class-w-o-children-in-nav-structure) post.

This does not entirely solve the problem as I am using `current_page_item` for C.P.T parent menu items, but it does achieve the desired outcome. Here is my `class`.

```
class My_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {  

  public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

    $post_type = get_post_type();
    $class_names = '';

    // Check if post_type - $item->attr_title returns the WP Menu custom link Title Attribute
    $class_names .= ($item->attr_title != '' && $item->attr_title == $post_type || in_array("current_page_item", $item->classes)) ? 'current_page_item' : '';

    // Prevent Blog menu item from getting the current_page_parent class when Custom Post Type
    if(!is_post_type_archive() && !is_singular(array( 'custom-one', 'custom-two'))){
    $class_names .= in_array("current_page_parent", $item->classes) ? ' current_page_parent' : '';
    }

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';

    $atts = array();
    $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
    $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
    $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
    $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

    $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

    $attributes = '';
    foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
        if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
            $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
            $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
        }
    }
    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ); 
  }

  public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $output .= "</li>\n";
  }

} // Walker_Nav_Menu
```